# meteor collections db.find() not a function (mid-development)

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Ok I'm at a loss.  Writing a Meteor React app...it creates a collection and does that part still.  I recently uploaded a currency formatter: react-currency-input from npm that did what I wanted and wrote to the mongo db, which I can access from the terminal without an issue.

But when running my app, it gives me two new reasons it crashes and I don't know why:

1. Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

This is weird because I am not defining proptypes anywhere in my react.

2.
Uncaught TypeError: Tickets.find is not a function

It is referencing this code in the error:

```
export default class TicketList extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        tickets: []
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('componentDidMount TicketList');
      this.ticketTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
        Meteor.subscribe('tickets');
        let tickets = Tickets.find({}).fetch();
        this.setState({ tickets });
      });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log('componentWillUnmount TicketList');
      this.ticketTracker.stop();
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea of where I can start looking to debug this or why I am getting these new bugs out of the blue?

Comment: First thing I'd check is if you are importing the Tickets collection properly.

Comment: Actually that was a good place to look! Thank you.

Comment: But it's still giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @John Smith pointed out - my ticket collection was no longer a default export so I had to add the {} wherever I imported it and that solved the main issue.  Thanks!